# Signing and publishing Android Application

Tags: android, mobile, publish, signing

I've got a problem to publish my Android Application.

here's what i've done,

so I have my application run on development environment (eclipse - testing using device), 
then i do right click on my project folder - android tools - export signed application package, then i create new key store and add my information there, then it'll produce the .apk

then i put it up on my own webserver (I intend to put it on my own web server and android market place as well)

but then, once i try to download my .apk from my testing handset - it said:
"cannot download. the content the content is not supported on this phone"

this is weird, since i do my testing on this same handset as well -.-! :(

so my question are:

1. what is the proper way to sign my app so it can be downloaded all the way through my own web server?
2. but I still can put it up on android market as well? - I have my android market account.

is there any walk-through for it?

Well Hope someone can give me the answer, I really appreciate your help!

Thanks & Cheers!

Comment: Have you checked the "Unknown sources-allow installation of non-market applications" found in Settings->Applications on your phone?

Comment: Yes I Did, but still doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 possible things I can see.

1. Your version of android you created your program in is higher than your phone. Ex. you created the project with Android 2.1 library and your phone is only Android 1.6
2. If you plugged in your phone and ran the program through eclipse onto your phone, if you try to make an .apk and install it on your phone with the program still there it will complain because the program already on your phone is for debugging and isn't signed. I've done this a lot and freaked out that it wasn't working.... Just uninstall it first and then try re-installing it with the apk.

It sounds more like #1 because you get a different error than the one you described above if it was #2.

Hope that helped!

Comment: 1. my uses sdk - min sdk version is 4 and targeted sdk version is 7 and i tested it on samsung galaxy s handset - from eclipse it's run well...

2. I format my phone before, so, for sure my handset is fresh when i try to download and install my app.